# Script works differently when ran from the terminal and ran from Python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, pipeline

I have a short bash script `foo.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z1-9' | fold -w 4 | head -n 1
```

When I run it directly from the shell, it runs fine, exiting when it is done

```
$ ./foo.sh 
m1un
$
```

but when I run it from Python

```
$ python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['./foo.sh'])"
ygs9
```

it outputs the line but then just hangs forever. What is causing this discrepancy?

Comment: try in terminal `cat /dev/urandom` and you see that it never stops. Probably `call()` thinks that `cat /dev/urandom` so it doesn't stop running. I can't get better explanation. If you try with `cat some_normal_file instead` of `cat /devurandom` then you don't have to this problem - probably standard file send EOF information.

Comment: This is a problem with python version. I tried with 2.6 and it hangs. But it worked with 3.5.1. Which version you are using? Did you try to switch to the newer?

Comment: @DawidGrabowski I'm using 2.7.6 -- I also am able to get it to work when I use 3 (3.4.3). Interestingly, although `python3 -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['./foo.sh'])"` does not hang, `python3 -c "import os; os.system('./foo.sh')"` *does* hang...

Comment: @furas Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the fact that `cat /dev/urandom` can continue forever; if the code in `foo.sh` was just `cat /dev/urandom` then both versions of running it would just spew on forever and if the code was just `cat /dev/urandom | head -n 1` both would terminate, though. There's something funny with this particular pipeline that I would like to understand. (This is actually a somewhat reduced-down version of a bigger problem with another couple process launches in between...).

Comment: @furas As for `call` thinking that `cat /dev/urandom` doesn't stop running, it's worth nothing that `call` doesn't know about `cat` directly. It just ran an executable file that happened to have a bash shebang, so bash is running it now AFAIK. (Maybe there's something weird about the way that cat will die in these situations that won't propagate, a weird signal boiling up or something?)

Comment: As a brief note, using Python 2 with the third-party backport subprocess32 like `python -c "import subprocess32 as subprocess; subprocess.call(['./foo.sh'])"` lets it exit -- it looks like this might be a matter of a fixed bug in the `subprocess` module..?

Comment: @MikeGraham I think it's related to [this issue](http://www.macaronikazoo.com/?p=607).

Comment: @DawidGrabowski Hmm, that doesn't seem applicable here, to me. Can you explain how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding the `trap -p` command to the bash script, stopping the hung python process and running `ps` shows what's going on:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

trap -p
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z1-9' | fold -w 4 | head -n 1

$ python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['./foo.sh'])"
trap -- '' SIGPIPE
trap -- '' SIGXFSZ
ko5o

^Z
[1]+  Stopped     python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['./foo.sh'])"
$ ps -H -o comm
COMMAND
bash
  python
    foo.sh
      cat
      tr
      fold
  ps
```

Thus, `subprocess.call()` executes the command with the `SIGPIPE` signal masked. When `head` does its job and exits, the remaining processes do not receive the broken pipe signal and do not terminate.

Having the explanation of the problem at hand, it was easy to find the bug in the python bugtracker, which turned out to be [issue#1652](https://bugs.python.org/issue1652).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Python 2 handling `SIGPIPE` in a non-standard way (i.e., being ignored) is already coined in Leon's answer, and the fix is given in the link: set `SIGPIPE` to default (`SIG_DFL`) with, e.g.,

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE,signal.SIG_DFL)
```

---

You can try to unset `SIGPIPE` from within your script with, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/bash

trap SIGPIPE # reset SIGPIPE

cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z1-9' | fold -w 4 | head -n 1
```

but, unfortunately, it doesn't work, as per the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap)

> Signals ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset.

---

A final comment: you have a useless use of `cat` here; it's better to write your script as:

```
#!/bin/bash

tr -dc 'a-z1-9' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 4 | head -n 1
```

Yet, since you're using Bash, you might as well use the `read` builtin as follows (this will advantageously replace `fold` and `head`):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -n4 a < <(tr -dc 'a-z1-9' < /dev/urandom)
printf '%s\n' "$a"
```

It turns out that with this version, you'll have a clear idea of what's going on (and the script will not hang):

```
$ python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['./foo'])"
hcwh
tr: write error: Broken pipe
tr: write error
$
$ # script didn't hang
```

(Of course, it works well with no errors with Python3). And telling Python to use the default signal for `SIGPIPE` works well too:

```
$ python -c "import signal; import subprocess; signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE,signal.SIG_DFL); subprocess.call(['./foo'])"
jc1p
$
```

(and also works with Python3).